# post_fork in Gunicorn shows unexpected number of workers

Tags: flask, gunicorn

Here is my gunicorn.conf.py file

```
workers = 2
worker_class = "sync"
timeout = 60

bind = "127.0.0.1:8080"

def post_fork(server, worker):
    cuda_set = {"12", "34"}
    # cuda_list = ["12", "34"]
    worker_pid = worker.pid
    num_running_workers = len(server.WORKERS)
    print(f"worker_pid is: {worker_pid}, number of running workers is: {num_running_workers}")
```

I expect the number of running workers will be 1 and 2 respectively, because I define workers as 2.  However, after running command

```
gunicorn -c gunicorn.conf.py app:app
```

I got this output

```
[2023-08-23 16:22:37 -0700] [95639] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 21.2.0
[2023-08-23 16:22:37 -0700] [95639] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8080 (95639)
[2023-08-23 16:22:37 -0700] [95639] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2023-08-23 16:22:37 -0700] [95648] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 95648
worker_pid is: 95648, number of running workers is: 0
[2023-08-23 16:22:37 -0700] [95649] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 95649
worker_pid is: 95649, number of running workers is: 1
```

I cannot figure it out.
Please help.